# bind proftpd only to localhost

Tags: debian, ftp, proftpd

How do i configure proftpd to only listen to connections on 127.0.0.1?
If i set

```
DefaultAddress localhost
```

in /etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf

and restart proftp i'm still able to login from another computer...

is this the wrong option? Or ist this just a stupid use case and no one but me would ever need such functionalty?!?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did you try using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`. Maybe `/etc/hosts` has something strange in there.

Failing that, the [ProFTPd FAQ](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/faq/linked/faq-ch4.html#AEN316) suggests using the Allow and Deny options, or run it from xinetd, or enable the tcp wrappers module and set that up.

Or of course you could use iptables.

Comment: using iptables was quick and easy :-)

Answer (score 2):

To get `proftpd` to listen only on localhost, you would use both `DefaultAddress` *and* `SocketBindTight`, like so:

```
DefaultAddress localhost
SocketBindTight on
```

By default, `proftpd` will listen on *all* interfaces for a given port (*e.g.* "*:21").  The `SocketBindTight` directive tells `proftpd` to bind "tightly" to the address/socket, rather than using a wildcard socket (resulting in *e.g.* "127.0.0.1:21").

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't look like there's an option inside the configuration file. This is one way to do it, which will also allow you to filter by username (using PAM):

Create a file called `/etc/security/proftpd.conf` containing the following lines:

```
+ : ALL : 127.0.0.1  
+ : ALL : localhost  
- : ALL : ALL
```

The + means allow, the second column is the username, and the third column is the hostname of the incoming connecion. So, for example, `+ : john : 127.0.0.2` will allow `john` to connect from `127.0.0.2`. `A -` denies them.

Next, modify `/etc/pam.d/proftpd` to add the following somewhere near the top (I make it the first line after session) to make it read the new file:

```
auth       required     pam_access.so accessfile=/etc/security/proftpd.conf
```

It should take effect immediately without the need for a service restart.

Comment: On Ubuntu 12.04, I had to also enable PAM authentication by uncommenting the line `# AuthOrder                     mod_auth_pam.c* mod_auth_unix.c` in `/etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf`.